# OS X / Finder - Right Click "New Folder with Selection" - how to Increase the Animation Effect Speed?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, finder, ux

I'm using Finder on OS X 10.9x.

The effect that pulls all the selected items into a new folder from the right click **"new folder with selection"** is really nice, but way too slow for me. Anyone know a terminal command that would increase the animation rate?